# Should you change a thermostat when changing your water pump

Tags: cooling-system, thermostat

Just got my water pump changed. Now my thermostat is trying to edge up.

Should you change your thermostat when you change your water pump?

Comment: What do you mean "trying to edge up"? Is it just running hotter than before? Or is it actually overheating?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to, but since your coolant system is already drained, it would be a good time to.  Standard thermostats are only about $10 and a $2 gasket.  Changing your thermostat is typically 2 bolts and a gasket.

Comment: Depending on the vehicle, both components _may_ be annoying to get to and are typically located close together. As long as you have everything pulled apart, why not spend another $10 and a few minutes on preventative maintenance? Last time I had a water pump replaced it involved removing the AC compressor and timing belt cover. I figured I may as well replace the $10, 15 year-old thermostat while all that other stuff was out of the way.

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason to do them together unless you have reason to believe the thermostat needs to be replaced, or unless you have an unusual vehicle in which the thermostat is hard to access without taking apart the same things you'd take apart to get to the water pump. Usually the water pump requires taking off the timing belt cover and a lot of other adjacent parts, whereas the thermostat is usually immediately accessible from above or below the engine at the point where the return radiator hose connects.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you're a pro or a diy type of person.  If you're a pro or you're short on time, I totally agree with @rpmerf.  As long as you're at it, why not save yourself the bother if it blows later on.

On the other hand, if you're just a do-it-yourself person with no real time constraints if it does blow, there's no real reason to replace it: thermostats don't have a particular life span, and there's no particular reason that you should have to replace it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

its a good idea to replace the thermostat whenever replacing a water pump. The thermostat may have suffered some damage during the overheating that occurred before the water pump failed. OK, That's the final word. ..Or it should be lol.